# Pseudo Streaming MP4 with php

Tags: php, html, video-streaming

i am trying to make the video seek using php file

this is my code

```html
<?php
$path = 'http://exmaple.com/video.mp4'; 
$mm_type="video/mp4"; 

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
");

readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file

exit();

?>
```

the video work but it is not possible to seek

Comment: Rather than doing this in PHP, why not just let your web server handle it?  It'd be far more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Seeking requires that your server support handling of the `Content-Range:` header

Comment: In addition to that, being an MP4, it needs to be encoded properly so the MOOV atom can be found.

Comment: Most browsers will seek to the end now to find the moov. But `faststart` is still best practice as eliminates and additional round trip.

Comment: That's awesome!  I didn't know that.

Comment: the video already encoded and headers moved to start, i can seek video when i use direct link in video player... but via php it does not work

Comment: @szatmary i use nginx with mp4 modules, the video seeking work but not when i use it in the php example

Comment: Because your php example does not handle `Content-Range:` It must return a `206 Partial Content` Not the entire file.

Comment: @szatmary sorry for being dump but what i should add to the php code